# Swift 1.2 not willing my NSString "+" map.reduce

Tags: cocoa, swift, mapreduce, nsstring, operator-overloading

Here is a code who worked perfectly in Swift 1.1

At the beginning of my class I have

```
var bytes = [UInt8]?()
```

later I have

```
func hexString() -> String? {
    if let b = bytes {
        return b.map({NSString(format: "%02x", $0)}).reduce("", +)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Swift 1.2 gives me

*Missing argument label 'combine:' in call*

and thus wants me to rephrase my map reduce this way

```
return b.map({NSString(format: "%02x", $0)}).reduce("", combine: +)
```

note the explicit **combine** for the second `reduce` argument. if I do that though I get another error on the `+`:

*Could not find an overload for '+' that accepts the supplied arguments*

This error makes no sense to me since what `NSString(format:)` produces is a NSString, so it should work with `+`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like that is because of disabled bridging for Swift 1.2. This replacement will produce no errors:

```
var bytes = [UInt8]?()

func hexString() -> String? {
    if let b = bytes {
        return b.map() {String(format: "%02x", $0)}.reduce("", combine: +)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks @valzevul Yes, this is what's driving the most crazy in my conversion ;) It's a good thing though, because this way we have to use more String than NSString!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is that NSString doesn't implement "+" operator, only String does. In Swift 1.1 the NSString was casted to String automatically.

That's why you should use String instead of NSString.

```
func hexString() -> String? {
    if let b = bytes { 
        return b.map({String(format: "%02x", $0)}).reduce("", combine: +)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ps4. See my comment to valzevul — you replied 2 minute after, the exact same answer! great :-)